# Update SQLite row only if a column is empty

Tags: php, sql, sqlite, sql-update, case

I have the following:

```
$query = $db->prepare("UPDATE name SET one=?,two=?,three=? WHERE id = ?");
$query->bindParam(1, $one);
$query->bindParam(2, $two);
$query->bindParam(3, $three);
$query->bindParam(4, $id);
```

`one` and `three` should always be updated.

However, how can I update `two` **only** if it is null/empty?

I can do this in a separate command, though how can I achieve this in one prepared statement?

I am using SQLite3

Comment: What is wrong with doing it in a different statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `CASE` expression for column `two`:

```
UPDATE name 
SET one=?,
    two=CASE WHEN two IS NULL THEN ? ELSE two END,
    three=? 
WHERE id = ?
```

Or with `COALESCE()`:

```
UPDATE name 
SET one=?,
    two=COALESCE(two, ?),
    three=? 
WHERE id = ?
```

Answer (score 0):

Use case

```
UPDATE name 
SET one=?,two=case when two is null or two = '' then ? else two end, three=? 
WHERE id = ?
```